# How to change the position of text "No data available in table" in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I need to change the position of the text which is coming from data-tables. is it possible to do ?

When ever their is no data in table the text coming from data-table is "no data available in table and  by default its position is left aligned.
Now i need that text to be center aligned to table.

I am using 1.9.4 version of jquery datatable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use this "td.dataTables_empty" class to position it via css

Comment: It _is_ center aligned by default -> **http://jsfiddle.net/b1yu24tr/** you have some custom CSS that overrides table.td align.

Comment: jquery.dataTables.css (1.9.4) line 38 : `table.dataTable td.center, table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
  text-align: center;
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

Use this class in your css to position it in the right way .

> "td.dataTables_empty"

.

Answer (score 3):

Adding following style aligns the text well

```
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
    text-align: center;    
}
```